New SB Refresh Behavior where Images are broken on Knowledge Articles
I handle our Sandbox refreshes and perform two each year.  We refresh a Dev, Full, and Partial SB.  Historically post refresh the images on knowledge articles would load without issue.  We just did a refresh on our FULL SB June 28th and this time after the refresh we found random knowledge articles with images broken.  Note the images are still loading just fine in production.  Any thoughts on why the sudden change for Knowledge Article image load issues in our FULL Sandbox?  Anyone else seeing this behavior too?  One interesting thing to note is:  I'm able to go to the Knowledge article with the broken image and edit it and upon clicking edit the images will load for me.  Then I publish and it's working as expected.  Again, we've never needed to do this before in our SB so curious why the sudden change.

Have you opened a case with Salesforce?

Yes I have and they are saying is normal expected behavior but we've been doing refreshes for years and haven't seen this behavior before so thought I would also reach out to the community to see if anyone else has seen a behavior change.
